# Does Entity Framework handle transaction by default on ExecuteFunction while calling transactions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

```
ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<GetStoredProcedure_Result>("StoredProcedure", parameter);
```

Does this code cover transaction automatically (by Entity Framework)? Or should I add transaction in the stored procedure as well?

Please provide any links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF6 every stored procedure call is wrapped in `Transaction`. But for the earlier versions of EF it will not cover automatically. You need to specify `TransactionScope` as following...

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
   //your code here
}
```

For more on transaction follow [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738523(v=vs.100).aspx).

I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248523/call-stored-procedure-inside-transaction-using-entity-framework) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109029/cant-i-call-a-stored-procedure-from-entity-framework-inside-a-transaction-scope) can help you in your case.

Comment: Again, if you really want to have transnational DB logic then it's always recommended to implement the same at DB end inside your procedure code logic rather in ADO.NET or in application code.

Comment: But according to this link it says the opposite (From what I understand) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx Wanted to make sure.

Comment: You should think of isolationlevel (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel.aspx).

Comment: EF implicitly supports transactions. If you are doing SaveChanges EF implicitly wraps commands in a db transaction such as SqlTransaction. By default, EF uses DbTransaction to take care of ops on a single instance of a db conn. Also EF supports over riding of the trans, so I guess for your case as gypsy suggesed you need to use TransactionScope().

Comment: So in my code while calling ExecuteFunction, if an error occurs in the execution of Stored Procedure, it doesn't roll back? And I need to implement transactionScope in C# or Transaction in SQL to achieve this? Is this what is implemented in the answer?

Comment: EF's default transaction isolation level can cover the `SaveChanges` operation. But in you case where you are executing a function you need to use `TransactionScope` @wintersolider

Comment: @wintersolider have you got your answer?